# How to group xcode 5 test cases into test suites

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testing, xcode5

I use xcode 5 test navigator to run my test, but one painful thing is that I need sometime to test whole layers of my app (say the models). I would like a way to group tests into logical units. I could probably use Test targets for that purpose but I don't think that's an efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a test case class for each of your logical units will group them in the test navigator. Choose File > New > File to add a new test case class to your project.

If you move the cursor over a test case class in the test navigator, a small Run button will appear next to the class. Click the button to run only the tests for that class.

Comment: I know that usage, but say I have a model layer with 10 classes. creating one TestCase for all 10 classes doesn't seems like a good idea. So I create a TestCase per model class and I would like to have a way to run all 10 TestCase without running other TestCases.

Comment: The only other alternatives I can think of are having multiple test targets or running all the tests when you test.

Comment: One could also create schemes that run only the tests you are interested in for the particular layer.