# Separate XCTest Test Classes

Tags: xcode6, ocmock, xctest

I have about 650 `XCTest` test cases contained in 35 different classes. I know by editing the product scheme or right-clicking tests in the Test Navigator I can disable specific test classes. What I'm wondering is if there's any way to group or separate classes?

In the Test Navigator all the test classes are ordered alphabetically so there's little organization and it's difficult to enable/disable groups of tests. Xcode also seems to like expanding each test cases so navigating the list is often hard. I noticed there's a button on the bottom of the list which allows you to "Show only tests in the currently selected scheme", however I haven't been able to determine how it works. Would I have to create multiple schemes or targets?

I should also mention I'm using `OCMock`.

Comment: I don't know of any way to group the classes, as you can see in the following question: [How to group xcode 5 test cases into test suits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142603/how-to-group-xcode-5-test-cases-into-test-suits)